# HttpRequest from JS to C# Http Listener

Tags: javascript, c#, httprequest, httplistener

I have this code to send a httprequest from JS

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:60006/", true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        alert('onload');
    };
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        alert('statechange');
    };
    xhr.send();
```

this code send  the http request correctly, 
I have this code on c# as a HttpListener

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var web = new HttpListener(); 
        web.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:60006/");  
        web.Start();

        var context = web.GetContext(); 
        var response = context.Response;

        const string responseString = "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>";

        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString); 
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length; 
        var output = response.OutputStream;

        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);            
        output.Close();

        web.Stop(); 
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The httpRequest from JS is received by the C# code, but I can not get the response value on the JS (Changing the alert on statechange and onload)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What do you see in the console? Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: What error your are getting n the console?